# Visual Studio 2010 (devenv) Hung Process After Closing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash, freeze, devenv

I have problem with Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 64-bit. After some time of work VS starts consuming ~50% CPU and UI responding slows down. When I close VS then UI disappear but process stay.

When I forgot to kill those hung processes at the end of day, I will end up with numerous devenv.exe processes.

I have reinstall Visual Studio and reinstall Windows and ended up with the same problem... doesn't change anything. Please help. :/

[image: devenv]

Comment: You might just have to kill them. It looks like a bug that wouldn't be a poor thing to report to Microsoft.

Comment: I try to remember to kill them but sometimes I forget. Of course this is not a solution.

Comment: Did you try attaching a debugger to the devenv.exe process?

Comment: Yes, I try but everything freezes. :/

Comment: Most of the time, this is due to 3rd party VS packages or addins. Can you try w/o them? or maybe reset your settings as described here: http://aspadvice.com/blogs/ssmith/archive/2007/08/20/Reset-Visual-Studio-Settings.aspx ?

Comment: Yes. I try it without any success.  :(

Comment: You may be able to create a dump file for the hanging instances. Start the task manager in \Windows\SysWow64 (devenv is 32 bits so you're better off with a 32 bit dump), right-click the process and pick Create dump file. You can then open the dump file in a debugger.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove and/or uninstall all third-party Visual Studio add-ins and extensions. Disabling is not good enough.

Visual Studio 2010 relies heavily on graphics. Therefore:

- Update your video driver.
- Turn off "Enable rich client visual
  experience"
- Turn off "Use Hardware graphics acceleration if
  available"

There are also temporary files that Visual Studio uses that may need to be cleared out.

- Clear out your %temp% folder.
- Clear out %AppData%\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
- Clear out %AppData%\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ProjectAssemblies

Your project and solution user settings may be corrupt due to so many "crashes".

- Delete .user and .suo files (you will lose the startup project, bookmarks, breakpoints, and other user settings specific to projects and solutions.)

Comment: I decided to change the hardware. The current was old and there are no new drivers. But... your answer give's me some breath. When I clear those folders then VS hangs less frequently.

Comment: @dario-g; In that case, another thing to try is the default Microsoft video driver for that adapter.

Comment: @dario-g: Check out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596642/visual-studio-soft-crashing-when-encountering-xaml-errors-in-initialize/

Answer (score 0):

Begin where you began before - it may seem overkill but this is the only way to be sure we are addressing everything short of hardware issues.

---

1. **Reinstall Windows** - make sure you are using a validly licensed copy, and patch the hell out of it *before* installing Visual Studio.

   *Note: I doubt it is a GPU driver issue, but it never hurts to use the most up to date driver and this is the place to do it right after a fresh OS install.*
2. **Install Visual Studio .Net 2010 but do not start it up**. Let it get the frameworks installed fresh.
3. Use Windows Update to **install the VS 2010 SP1** patch, and **any/all patches for .Net** frameworks.

   *Make an images for yourself right here so you have something to build from if you need to try this again. It will save you lots of time.*
4. Fire up Visual Studio, and test your closing **before installing anything else**.

If it does not work here, there's likely some conflict between PC hardware and window OS, and you should try to find this symptom in other applications to get more info.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i would be looking for:

1. Does it happen EVERY TIME?
2. Does it happen after you debug your project ? does it happen for ALL projects?
3. Does it also happen when you don't load any projects? (simply start the IDE and wait).
4. Does it happen after a debug session of your application? maybe the application is not closed properly?
5. Do you have any other apps running at the same time that may cause this? try reproducing with a minimal set of apps/services running.
6. What are you doing exactly when it starts freezing ? anything in particular?

I would try to get 2-3 memory dumps at the time of hanging, post it here as well as to MSFT people. That would be a good start.